# How do you bind multiple dynamic IPs to different programs?

Tags: windows, networking, router, ip

As the title implies, how do I make **specific programs** on my computer use different **dynamic** public IP addresses? Is it even possible?

From what I know, my ISP assigns a dynamic IP for me. I can change this IP by restarting my router. With that said, is it possible to somehow trick it into thinking a specific program is a different computer all together? Would I even need to do that or is there an easier way to achieve the same result?

For example, I would like to be able to open 2 instances of a web browser and have both use different public IP's such that if I were to go to a website like `whatismyipaddress.com`, it would show two different IP's. Ideally, the same would apply to any program.

Comment: this is kinda where VPNs and proxies come in. Most ISPs would consider it stealing if you somehow used more than your contractual allotment of public IPs and boot you over TOS violations. instead look into using services outside your ISP that can affect your external visibility.

Comment: Sure, jumping through some hoops could make this possible. However, I seriously doubt you have multiple public IP addresses at the same time.

Comment: Additionally, unless the program specifically provides a feature for setting a local address/interface, you won't be able to bind an address to a specific program. one example might be a webserver, where you can run multiple sites on a server, each assigned to an IP, but they all must be IPs assigned to the box. You can probably find browser extensions that can allow you to vary your connectivity between browser instances.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I make specific programs on my computer use different dynamic public IP addresses? Is it even possible?

No, binding an application to a listening address is a static operation. In particular, the **local** address on the machine where your application is running won't be the dynamic public IP in the first place, and you bind your application to this local address.

> From what I know, my ISP assigns a dynamic IP for me.

And your router may or may not get this address. It may also get a "private" IP, with your ISP doing network address translation (NAT).

> For example, I would like to be able to open 2 instances of a web browser and have both use different public IP's

And this has nothing to do with binding on an address: Your web browsers are not listening to incoming requests at a specific address, they are sending out requests.

So it's a completely different thing.

To be able to use different public IP's for outgoing requests, you first have to have different public IP's (for example, by having two ISPs, or a VPN).

Then, depending on the way you can route to those addresses, you need to run your browser in such a way that one browser routes to one address, and the other to the other one. They'll both very likely use a **local** IP address as the source, and not your public IP's, but NAT will take care of that.

You can do this for example with a VM, or on Linux with network namespaces (and AFAIK, Windows has no equivalent).

Comment: Binding is optional when making outgoing connections but still possible. Otherwise, you could not make connections from a specific source IP address if your PC has multiple.

Comment: @DanielB but you cannot bind on a public IP address that is not present on your local machine...

Comment: Sure. Emulating it is possible though, it would need additional source NAT rules to work.

Comment: Additionally, you can only bind an app to an interface/address if the app provides that configuration as an option. most programs do not allow you to select a interface or address, and leave it up to the os default.